# How to query ElementArrayFinder?

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I have two radio buttons that bind to the same model value and I want to find the one that has value attribute set to 'name'

```
<li>
    <label class="checkbox-inline nopaddingleft" for="radio1">
      <input name="radio1" type="radio" id="radio1"  class="checkbox-inline margin-right-five" data-ng-model="clientSearchType" value="name" data-ng-change="onClientSearchTypeChanged()" tabindex="6" />Client Name
    </label>

    <label class="checkbox-inline" for="radio1">
        <input name="radio1" type="radio" id="radio2" class="checkbox-inline margin-right-five" data-ng-model="clientSearchType" value="number" data-ng-change="onClientSearchTypeChanged()" tabindex="7" />Client Number</label>
 </li>
```

How does one perform this search? I can find two elements like this

```
element.all(by.model('clientSearchType'))
```

This returns per documentation "ElementArrayFinder" type. can I find from that result element that has value set to 'name'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

v1.0 of protractor added a `filter` method to `ElementArrayFinder` which means you can now do this:

```
var expectedValue = 'name';

element.all(by.model('clientSearchType')).filter(function(elementFinder){
    return elementFinder.getAttribute('value').then(function(value){
        return value === expectedValue;
    });
});
```